# Docker reporting that my Linux kernel doesn't support cgroup cpu real-time period

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cgroups

I've configured Docker on my Ubuntu 18.04 Server to expose its API so I can create and deploy Docker containers via REST requests, which I need to add certain features to my project. This worked fine for first few endpoints I tried. However, when I attempt to create a new Docker container (the main point of the exercise), I get the message:

```
{"message": "Your kernel does not support cgroup cpu real-time period"}
```

Is this true? Alternatively is it instead that I need to set something up to enable this functionality, or is Docker reporting incorrectly?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@./test-data/docker-create-api-test.json" http://localhost:1112/containers/create
{"message":"Your kernel does not support cgroup cpu real-time period"}
```

Very grateful for any assistance given as this functionality is critical to my project.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the docker command that produces this. (Not via your interface, and not speculation. Test it).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Added but by definition this is not a Docker command in any usual sense. The Docker API is a REST API which is supposed to function via REST calls such as the curl call pictured above. https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/ https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerList . I have altered my environment variables to expose this API via http (tcp) which by default is served via the unix protocol.

Comment: well recompiling the kernel with this option (https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RT_GROUP_SCHED.html) could be an option

Comment: That sounds pretty hardcore. I'll look into it.

Comment: in case you don't find any other (probably better) solution, bear in mind that from now on, for your project needing this critical feature, you'll have the additional burden of having an adequate kernel. That means you can't run this container on any docker, but only one with the recompiled kernel etc. I would try anything else than this

Comment: The container is just the standard Docker Ubuntu image. I used the API test code on the Docker site, which is why it confused me that it decided to throw this error, as I'd have assumed what is possible with the Docker run command is possible with the API. I just want to spin up coding sandboxes on demand. Nothing really special. Doesn't seem at the moment like I will be able to spin up Docker containers programatically.

Comment: Please don't post text as a picture of text. It makes it hard to read.

Comment: My guess that all the information is in that json file.

Comment: are you sure it's of any importance? looks like a warning. Your question made think this specific feature is needed for your specific project.

Comment: The info in the json file is a copy paste of the default info given here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate with no variation

Comment: @A.B sadly it does not create the container

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor could you provide any rationale for why the info in that json file would produce that particular error?

Comment: All I know is that there is no relevant information in the visible part of the command. Therefore ....

Comment: So maybe Docker itself is not configured correctly.  Like configured with rt options when it shouldn't be. check there (and do not do it, remove it if found it was done): https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-realtime-scheduler

Comment: Thanks @A.B that seems hopefully a less dangerous line of enquiry. I'll read through those.

Comment: I looked through those and it seems I've seen these before. All that I could find was --cap-add=sys_nice which seems like it would change the docker container, whereas the error seems to be to do with the host.

Answer (score 0):

In the official Docker example that I had wrongly assumed would work as a test body, there was the following line:

```
"CpuRealtimePeriod": 1000000,
```

Which sets a value that, it seems, is not supported by most or perhaps any out of the box Linux distros. Arch Linux master race ;).